# creating sharepoint detail page with seo optimization

Tags: sharepoint-list, seo

I have a list contains items of announcements, here how it looks;

```
Title                    Content
test-title               ...
another-test-title       ...
```

There is a table list these items when one of them clicked it redirected to detail page of that announcement and url looks like; "http://...?Id=2".

Now my chief ask me to make this detail page with seo optimization and url should contains title of the page. it should looks like:"http://.../announcement/test-title".

How can I achieve it in sharepoint properly? Should I create a column in list for url.

Or do I need create content types. and most important: can I find any sample of this processes ?

Whatever your advice to solution please eloborate it with clear demonstration.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: So this is a public website?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman yes, it will be public.